# Show that $f(x)|2+g(x)|$ is continuous iff $g(x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I ave the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+2x+5}$.

I need to prove that the function $f(x)|2+g(x)|$ is continuous if and only if $g(x)$ is continuous, for any function $g(x)$.

One side is obvious, because if $g(x)$ is continuous, so this is a product of continuous functions. How can I prove the other direction?

Can I give one example for a specific discontinuous $g(x)$, and show that the product is discontinuous?

Comment: Is the desired claim true?  Say $g(x)=0$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $g(x)=-4$ if $x\notin \mathbb Q$.  Then $g(x)$ isn't continuous anywhere but $|2+g(x)|$ is a constant (it's just $=2$ for all $x$).

Answer (score 1):

Absolute value of a function may be continuous without the function being continuous. Thus the iff statement is not true, that is you may have $$|2+g(x)|$$ continuous without $g(x)$ being continuous.

Answer (score 0):

While the comment and the answer have already pointed out that your statement is false. I'll address the following logical error that you made:

> Can I give one example for a specific discontinuous $g(x)$, and show that the product is discontinuous?

Even if the statement *were* true, giving one possible example wouldn't have proven the statement. The best way to observe that is by actually constructing an example now!
Let $$g(x) = \begin{cases}-2 & x = 0 \\ 
4&x\neq 0\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $g$ is discontinuous (at $0$). It is easy to show that the product is discontinuous as well.

Thus, showing one specific example clearly cannot prove the statement since we've just shown an example even though the statement was incorrect to begin with.